# Resource balancing between users?

Tags: linux, cpu

I have a cluster of Linux computers that are shared by many users and want to ensure that no user can flood the systems and effectively prevent others from running anything.  i.e. If user `A` is running a single CPU intensive job and user `B` is running 50 I would like user `A`'s job to effectively have up to 50% CPU usage.  Currently in this scenario user `B` seems to get 50X the CPU resources that user `A` does.

I've looked at `cgroups`  since it sounded like exactly what I wanted.  However, in a single user scenario (i.e. if user `A` doesn't want any CPU time) I would like user `B` to have access to the full compute resources of the system.  It's not clear to me how to do this with cgroups.  All references I've found talk about placing hard limits such as "user `B` can have up to 50% CPU".